# MSBuild AssemblyInfo CreateItem failed

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

We are running MSBuild from CruiseControl.net.
We have one branch that, when built on the build server via CC, fails with the following error:

```
<target name="UpdateAssemblyInfo" startTime="11/13/2012 18:48:35" elapsedTime="00:00:01" elapsedSeconds="1" success="false">        
<error code="MSB4018" file="C:\Continuous Integration Projects\Project\Release\Build\Master.build" line="88" column="5" timeStamp="11/13/2012 18:48:36"><![CDATA[The "CreateItem" task failed unexpectedly.System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
```

The error goes on for many more lines...

The task is defined in master.build:

```
<Target Name="UpdateAssemblyInfo">    
    <CreateItem Include="$(SourcePath)\**\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">      
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="UpdateAssemblyInfoFiles"/>
    </CreateItem>    
    <Attrib Files="@(UpdateAssemblyInfoFiles)" Normal="true" />    
    <AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="@(UpdateAssemblyInfoFiles)"   AssemblyVersion="$(CCNetLabel)" AssemblyFileVersion="$(CCNetLabel)"/>  
</Target>
```

How can we figure out which AssemblyInfo.cs is causing the problem?
Is there some way to add diagnostic output to the master.build file?

Thanks for any insight...

Comment: Can you provide line 88 of the master.build file?

Comment: Line 88 is the <CreateItem /> line.

Answer (score 0):

Set the verbosity level of MSBuild to `diag` and check the output. Assuming you are using CCNET's [`<msbuild>` task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/MsBuild_Task) this should be it:

```
<msbuild>
  <!-- ... -->
  <buildArgs>/v:diag</buildArgs>
</msbuild>
```

Comment: Thanks, output will appear in the log file?

Comment: to get the output to the logfile you need to sset the MSBuild logger to CCNET's ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll or to the Rodemeyer logger (http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Improved+MSBuild+Integration) and to merge the created XML log via the merge task

Comment: At this point I would suggest running msbuild from the command line and seeing the output on screen, rather than configuring ccnet, especially as it would be a temporary change.

Comment: It should be just `msbuild "C:\Continuous Integration Projects\Project\Release\Build\Master.build" /v:diag`

Answer (score 0):

The exception does state that the path or file name exceeds the length constraints.

`System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

As `AssemblyInfo.cs` is less than `260` characters in length we can deduce that it doesn't like the path.

Are you able to check to see if the path part is `248` characters or more?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There are ~60 AssemblyInfo.cs files in the solution; I can't find any with a total path length >260.  Perhaps it is choking on paths that contain something like: \A.B.C\D.E.F.G\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: In which case I think you'll have to take a look at the detailed msbuild output. See my comment on @The Chairman's answer